# He has arranged to go there on Monday for you. (Is this sentence correct?)

Tags: grammar

> He has arranged for you to go there on Monday

vs.

> He has arranged to go there on Monday for you.

The location of 'for you' matters here?

Answer (score 13):

In this exact case, the position of "adverb of purpose" ***for you*** can change the meaning...

> 1: *He has arranged **for you** to go there on Monday*
> (*he* made the arrangements, but it's *you* who will go there)

> 2: *He has arranged to go there on Monday **for you***
> (*he* made the arrangements, and *he* will go there ***for your benefit***)

The basic principle is that *by default*, the element modified by an adverbial phrase is the *nearest preceding*<sup>1</sup> element for which it makes sense. In this case, there are two different verb-based elements that *could* be modified by ***for you*** (the "arranging" OR the "going"), so we normally choose the "nearest".

Note that the adverbial element can be moved even *closer* to the verb it modifies in #2 above...

> 3: *He has arranged to go there **for you** on Monday*
> (means *exactly* the same as #2 above)

---

<sup>1</sup> Sometimes, the nearest *following* element. For example, although it's relatively uncommon phrasing, we could have...

> 4: ***For you**, he has arranged to go there on Monday*

...which would *probably* be understood to match #2 above - but because it's relatively unusual, we *might* understand it as #1 (especially if that made more sense in the exact context).

Comment: Good answer. In this context, I would interpret “go there for you on Monday” as meaning, go there *instead of you*. That is, go there on your behalf, taking your place.

Comment: Yes - it's extremely difficult to contrive a context where "for you" *didn't*  mean "instead of you / on your behalf" if it's placed immediately after "go there" as per my example 3. Maybe something where it would obviously be impossible for him to do something on someone else's behalf: *He has arranged to **give birth in the hospital for her** when the baby arrives*. But I don't like it.

Comment: I think, “I voted for you in the last election,” works, because “vote for” is a fixed phrase, and we have different ways to say I cast a proxy vote or dropped off someone else’s ballot.

Comment: @Davislor: Nah. I always voted for my wife because she couldn't be trusted to choose the right party! It's not really so much that ***vote for*** is a "fixed phrase" - it's more that *in your favour* is a far more credible interpretation than *on your behalf* in almost all contexts. But ***root for*** - now *there's* a collocation that probably never means *instead of you, on your behalf*. (Unless you're an amorous boy pig rooting for truffles for your would-be sow! :)

Comment: My friend couldn’t make it to the game, so he gave me his ticket and I rooted for him for the home team.

Comment: i don’t think the “voted for my spouse” example works. However, that might be because I live in a country where that would be illegal. A caregiver can fill out a ballot for a disabled person in my state, but is supposed to do it according to their wishes.

Comment: You're just confirming my point. Your interpretation is primarily based on the meaning you consider *likely*, not the "literal" meaning(s) of the text.

Comment: I think I’m saying,  I can construct sentences where “for them” would not be interpreted as “in place of them” or “acting on behalf of them,” and this does not require more than one word of additional context. You might be onto why that is, but even in contexts where there are proxy votes (such as shareholder meetings), I don’t think “voted for them” is normally used that way.

Comment: ***Syntactically***, the construction under consideration here is inherently ambiguous in most contexts, but ***semantically*** it's usually easy to pick out the most reasonable interpretation. And sometimes different people with identical "contextual" background knowledge might settle on different interpretations. My answer above simply outlines the general syntactic tendency - which semantic *specifics* can invariably override.

Answer (score 3):

After verbs, like "arrange", which take a to-verb after them, the subject of the to-verb is assumed to be the same as the first verb. So in your second sentence, "he" both arranges and goes there on Monday. The "for you" at the end is understood to mean something like "*for your benefit*" or "*on your behalf*".

If you want the to-verb to have a different subject than the first verb, you can insert one with *[ "for" + subject ]*. So in your first sentence, "he" arranges, but "you" go there on Monday.